# Python install in Bash but not in Windows Cmd

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I downloaded the bash terminal for Windows and I see that Python is already installed:

[image: Image1]

I try to run Python in the Cmd terminal and it doesn't work and it makes the same in Visual Studio  [image: Image2]

What do I need to do so I can run Python in Visual Studio Code? I don't want to reinstall Python on Windows.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow take a look at the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: What do you mean you installed "bash terminal to Windows"? Do you mean git-bash or WSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to reinstall 
I'm guessing that  you path environment differs to one that you have in bash
you have couple of options

- you can [change vscode default shell](http://azurepost.com/change-shell-visual-studio-code-terminal/)
- copy output of `which python` from bash and run `set PATH=%PATH%;{output_of_which_python_in_bash}`

Comment: Thank you very much Mojtba. I change the shell in vscode and it do work